# how to prompt the user for for input repeatedly in php

Tags: php, arrays

here is what I want to do, i want to build a program that prompts the user for a string, stores the string in an array and prompts the user for another string, stores that string in an array and repeats the process 5 times, but every time I run the program, the string gets erased and it stores the same string 5 times, how can i modify this php code such that it does what I said? I tried using readline() but it doesn't work, it says it is an undefined function.

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "GET">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "tell" >
<br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>

<?php

$tester = array();
$counter = 5;

while ($counter > 0)
{
echo "please enter a criteria";
$name = $_GET['tell'];
array_push($tester,$name);
$counter = $counter - 1;
}

print_r($tester);

?>
```

Comment: You should replace $tester by $_SESSION['tester'] (need `<?php session_start(); ` at the beginning of the file), and remove `while($counter > 0)` : you should test if count($_SESSION['tester']) < 5.

Comment: "Criteria" is plural. "Criterion" is singular.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only runs when the page loads, so your code is only getting one value from $_GET.  In order to do this, you have to start a session and store your array in a session variable.

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
 if($_GET['tell']) {
   $tester = $_SESSION['tester'];

   array_push($tester,$_GET['tell']);

   $_SESSION['tester'] = $tester;
 }

 if(count($tester) < 5) {
   //display your form to ask the user for more information
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps doing it client-side using Javascript might be a better option, depending on the OP's particular case.

Comment: I agree, ajax would be a better solution.